# Error while loading assemblies: /bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/libHarfBuzzSharp.dll

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, harfbuzz

Error while loading assemblies: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/project.iOS/6b01e66516e8420be8424059207235df/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/libHarfBuzzSharp.dll.

I had recently upgraded my packages in xamarin iOS project and also visual studio to 16.7.4 version .Now I'm unable to build the iOS Project . Earlier it was building fine and able to deploy to a simulator.

I had delected bin, obj and rebuild the solution but the error still persists.

Please help me to figure out the root cause of this error.

Comment: Try to update the  Xcode to the latest version .Then create a new simulator and try again .

Comment: It is already updated to 12.0.1 latest

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help -> Send Feedback -> report a problem**  .

Comment: I have reported the problem . Link => https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1225144/error-while-loading-assemblies-biniphonesimulatordebuglibharfbuzzsharpdll.html .  Please have a look into it.